# Grunt watches only folders with matching files

Tags: gruntjs, glob, watch

I'm building a grunt script that needs to watch aproject folder and trigger a task when a file is added, changed or deleted. I thought that the `grunt-contrib-watch` was the package that could do it.

Now I experience some problems, when I run it when there are no `.php` files present then:

- The task is **not** triggered when a new file is created.
- The task is **not** triggered when a file is deleted.
- The task is **not** triggered when a file is changed.

When I run the watch task and there is for example a `.php` file inside the `/workbench/temp` folder, then:

- The task **is** triggered when a new file is created inside `/temp`.
- The task **is** triggered when a file is deleted inside `/temp`.
- The task **is** triggered when a file is changed inside `/temp`.
- The task is **not** triggered when a new file is created outside `/temp`.
- The task is **not** triggered when a file is deleted outside `/temp`.
- The task is **not** triggered when a file is changed outside `/temp`.

It looks like the `watch` task is making a list of directories to watch, and that it only include the directories that have files that matches the `files` option from the watch task.

How can I watch the whole given directory including all sub-folders (and not yet exisiting folders)?

My watch task:

```
        "workbench-php": {
            files: [ '../../laravel-test/workbench/**/*.php' ],
            tasks: [ 'test' ]   
        },
```

Comment: Could it be something simple like `'../../laravel-test/workbench/**/*.*'` instead of `'../../laravel-test/workbench/**/*.scss'`? Not sure I entirely understand why you are running a sass job with php files though.

Comment: @pherris Sorry pasted the wrong task :P. Updated the question. The problem stays when you cange all `php` to `scss`.